# object variable or with block variable not set 91

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

this excel VBA sometimes drives me crazy!

I want to create a pivot table, from this table :

main table

[image: main table]

and I managed to do it! yes I got the pivot table. but when I run the code for the second time I got this error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

the code:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

Dim rawdataSheet As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long

Set rawdataSheet = Sheets("Financials")
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = rawdataSheet.Range("A4:R" & lrow)

SrcData = Worksheets("Financials").Name & "!" & rng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)    

'Create a new worksheet
 Set sht = Worksheets("mypivot2")
'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A4").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
 Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
 Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable78")

 pvt.PivotFields("CU").Orientation = xlRowField
 pvt.PivotFields("Period").Orientation = xlColumnField

End Sub
```

the error happens at this line :

```
pvt.PivotFields("CU").Orientation = xlRowField
```

what is the problem? and why did it work in the first time but not for the second time.

Comment: It seems that you are naming the pivot table `PivotTable78`. So, when you are creating it again (without deleting the first pivot table) then the new creating of another pivot table with the same name will fail. You cannot have more than one pivot table in an Excel file with the same name. Hence `pvt` will be nothing and changing the `Orientation` of nothing should yield an error. I'd suggest that you either delete the prior pivot table first or you assign a new name at each run (dynamic name generation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reson you are getting the error message second time running your code, is because you already have the **"PivotTable78"** set-up, so when you are trying to create it again with the same name you get a run-time error.

The way to resolve it, is by "catching" the `pvt` object, to see if it already exists. If it does, you only need to refresh the Pivot with the latest Pivot Cache. If it's not, it means the Pivot Table doesn't exist, and you need to create it.

This is done by adding the line : `If pvt Is Nothing Then` right after `Set pvt = sht.PivotTables("PivotTable78")` in the code below.

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivotTable()

Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rawdataSheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range    
Dim lrow As Long

Set rawdataSheet = Sheets("Financials")

With rawdataSheet
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A4:R" & lrow)
    SrcData = .Name & "!" & rng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
End With

' Set "mypivot2" to sht worksheet object >> where the Pivot Table we be located
Set sht = Worksheets("mypivot2")

' range of Pivot Table start location
StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A4").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set pvt = sht.PivotTables("PivotTable78")

On Error GoTo 0
If pvt Is Nothing Then
    'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:="PivotTable78")

    pvt.PivotFields("CU").Orientation = xlRowField
    pvt.PivotFields("Period").Orientation = xlColumnField    
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    pvt.ChangePivotCache pvtCache
    pvt.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```